# JSF 1.1 : passing parameter from commandButton

Tags: jsf

I'm blocked with an application on JSF 1.1

I have a c:foreach loop and I want on my loop to pass my object into my function behind an h:commandButton

```
<c:forEach var="userConnect" items="${connectedUsersManagedBean.listUsers}">
    <tr onclick="testNico(this)">
        <td>${userConnect.login}</td>
        <td>${userConnect.ip}</td>
        <td>
            <h:commandButton id="deleteSelectedUser" 
                actionListener="#{connectedUsersManagedBean.disconnectUser}"
                value="Déconnecter" 
                styleClass="commandButton btnCancel">
                <f:attribute name="userAttribute" value="#{userConnect.login}" />
                <!-- <fparam name="id" value="{userConnect.login}" /> -->
                <!--<set var="testnico" value="testnico" scope="request" /> -->
            </h:commandButton> 
        </td>
    </tr>           
</c:forEach>
```

With f:param it was okay for a string, but when I try to pass my userConnect to the function, it doesn't work.

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried invoking userConnect.login from your controller - `connectedUsersManagedBean` ?

```
action="#{connectedUsersManagedBean.loginUser(userConnect)}"
```

with a function inside the `connectedUsersManagedBean`:

```
public void loginUser(yourtype userConnect) {
    userConnect.login();
}
```

this should work assuming you have a Servlet 3.0 compatible container (such as Tomcat 7 or glassfish 3)

Comment: i've tried but at work we still tomcat 6 for this application, so it don't work but thank's for the answer :)